# Flutter : Sort list by quantity

Tags: flutter, dart

i want sort my list `List<Product>` by quantity.
i have `List of size` inside `List of color` inside `List of product`

like this :

```
List<Product> _products = [
  //quantity is 1
  Product(
      productId: '0',
      purchasingPrice: 14.99,
      productTitle: 'Empty',
      productColors: [
        ProductColors(
            colorName: 'Red',
            colorHex: 'ff000d',
            productSize: [
              ProductSizes(
                  size: 'L',
                  quantity: 0
              ),
              ProductSizes(
                  size: 'M',
                  quantity: 1
              ),
              ProductSizes(
                  size: 'S',
                  quantity: 0
              )
            ]
        )
      ]
  ),
  //quantity is 5
  Product(
      productId: '1',
      purchasingPrice: 39.99,
      productTitle: 'Empty',
      productColors: [
        ProductColors(
            colorName: 'Black',
            colorHex: '000000',
            productSize: [
              ProductSizes(
                  size: 'XL',
                  quantity: 1
              ),
              ProductSizes(
                  size: 'L',
                  quantity: 2
              ),
              ProductSizes(
                  size: 'M',
                  quantity: 2
              )
            ]
        )
      ]
  ),
];
```

The first item has 1 piece and the Second  has 5 pieces.

I have never dealt with nested list :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add an `int` field `totalSize` to the class `Product`.

Here's how you can sort the list `_products`

```dart
int getTotalProductSize(Product product){
  int totalSize = 0;
  for(ProductColor productColor in product.productColors){
    for(int i=0; i<productColor.productSize.length; i++){
      totalSize += productColor.productSize[i].quantity;
    }
  }

  return totalSize;
}

for(Product product in _products){
  product.totalSize = getTotalProductSize(product);
}

_products.sort((a, b) => a.totalSize.compareTo(b.totalSize));
```

Please note that having such complex models is never recommended.